# Google REST API ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION

Tags: php, rest, google-authentication

I tried to use PHP cURL for Google REST API to send SMS

```
$data = array(
    'phoneNumber' => '+6512341234'
);

$verify = curl_init();
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_URL, "https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:sendVerificationCode?key=mykeyhere");
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($verify, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($verify);

var_dump($response);
```

But it shows me error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION",
        "errors": [
            {
                "message": "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs when the ability for users to create accounts in Identity Platform / Firebase Auth is turned off.

In Identity Platform, there is a checkbox in the `Settings > Users Actions` called `Enable create (sign up)`. If this is unchecked, then the 'sendVerificationCode' operation will fail.

[Image of the settings in GCP Identity Platform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Bo8.png)